# For a distribution function $F(x)$ and constant $a$, integral of $F(x + a) - F(x)$ is $a$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-integral

> For any distribution function and any $a \geq 0$, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (F(x+a)-F(x))dx = a$.

In this case, "distribution function" means a right continuous function F with $F(-\infty) = 0$, $F(\infty)= 1$.

This problem comes after a section in the book on mathematical expectation, so I suspect I should use some property of expectation to prove it. Expectation appears to be something that applies to random variables, so I think I should be somehow transforming the problem into something in terms of expectations of random variables, but I'm not sure how. I know that given a distribution function, I can get a probability measure, but I'm not sure how to go from there to a random variable and actually get a relation between the expectation of the random variable and this integral. I'm sure whether this is the right way to go about this problem, but if it is, I'm missing a connection somewhere.

Comment: can you tell me which book are you referring ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ is a random variable with distribution function $F$, then
$$
F(x+a)-F(x)=P(x<X\leq x+a)={\rm E}[\mathbf{1}_{x<X\leq x+a}].
$$
Since everything is non-negative we have by Tonelli that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty (F(x+a)-F(x))\,\mathrm dx={\rm E}\Big[\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbf{1}_{x<X\leq x+a}\,\mathrm dx\Big].
$$
Now evaluate the inner integral and conclude.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but could you please elaborate on how to evaluate the inner integral?

Comment: @Ant: Note that $\mathbf{1}_{x<X\leq x+a}=\mathbf{1}_{X-a\leq x<X}$ and hence the integral is $\int_{X-a}^X\mathrm dx=a$.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much :D

Comment: This looks so obvious now that you've said it. I'm just having some weird kind of cognitive difficulty moving between ideas from measure theory and ideas from probability.