# Integral of cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Yesterday I stumbled upon this question:

[For a distribution function $F(x)$ and constant $a$, integral of $F(x + a) - F(x)$ is $a$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958265/for-a-distribution-function-fx-and-constant-a-integral-of-fx-a-fx)

It is basically proved that if $F(x)$ is a cumulative distribution function, then $$\int_{\mathbb R} F(x+a) - F(x) \ dx = a$$

I understood the proof that was given, but it got me thinking:

Let's suppose $F \in C^\infty$. Then I can write $$F(x+a) - F(x) = f(x) a + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{F^{(k)}(x)}{k!}a^k$$

However, since $\int_\mathbb R f(x) = 1$, we have

$$\int_{\mathbb R} F(x+a)-F(x) \ dx= a + \int_\mathbb R \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{F^{(k)}(x)}{k!}a^k \ dx$$

Is it true then that $$\int_\mathbb R \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{F^{(k)}(x)}{k!}a^k \ dx= 0$$ for all $a$ if $F \in C^\infty$ or am I misinterpreting something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $F\in C^\infty$ doesn't suffice for the Taylor series to represent $F$ (the Taylor series generally doesn't converge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, assuming the density $f$ is analytic and such that every derivative is integrable and that one can exchange summation and integral, you proved that, for every $k\geqslant1$, $$\int_\mathbb Rf^{(k)}(x)\mathrm dx=0.$$
Note that $C^\infty$ is not enough to guarantee the function is equal to its Taylor series and to exchange summation and integral.

Comment: You are right, sorry

Comment: Thank you very much! I think it is clearer now. I have two observation though: 1) Given that we can exchange summation and integral, dont we first need to prove that $\int_\mathbb R f^{(k)}(x)dx \ge 0$ to conclude that is actually $\int_\mathbb R f^{(k)}(x)dx =  0$?

2) Anyhow, isn't it true that if $\int_\mathbb R f(x) dx$ converges, then $\int_\mathbb R f'(x) dx = 0$  (provided that $f'$ exists continuos) ? This should make the statement in the question trivial

Comment: It is rather direct (and classical) to build densities $f$ that are sums of "spikes" such that $f'$ is smooth but not integrable.

Comment: Uhm, I'll have to look into that. Thank you Did for all these great answers!