# Conditions for integration of difference between offset cumulative distribution functions

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I would like to solve the following integral:

$\int_{-T}^\infty [ F(T+s)-F(s)]ds$

Where T is a constant, and F(s) is a cumulative distribution function for a random variable $s \in [0,\infty)$.

Following the result as given in the question:
[For a distribution function $F(x)$ and constant $a$, integral of $F(x + a) - F(x)$ is $a$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958265/for-a-distribution-function-fx-and-constant-a-integral-of-fx-a-fx)

I believe that the answer is as follows:

$\int_{-T}^\infty [ F(T+s)-F(s)]ds= \int_{-\infty}^\infty [ F(T+s)-F(s)]ds\\
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_s^{s+T}[ f(y)]dyds \\
= \int_s^{s+T} \int_{-\infty}^\infty[ f(s)]dsdy \\
=T.$

However, I am confused as to why a similar method would not work for the following integral (with lower limit changed to zero):

$\int_{0}^\infty [ F(T+s)-F(s)]ds$

I am tempted to write:

$\int_{0}^\infty [ F(T+s)-F(s)]ds= \int_{0}^\infty \int_s^{s+T}[ f(y)]dyds \\
= \int_s^{s+T} \int_{0}^\infty[ f(s)]dsdy \\
=T,$

but this clearly cannot be correct. I do not have any knowledge of measure theory. Assuming that my assertions are themselves correct, is there any intuitive explanation as to why the solution to the second integral is incorrect, whilst that for the first is valid?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: In the integration, $f$ is a function of $y$. You cannot change that to the function of $s$ i.e. $f(s)$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I had convinced myself that this was valid as a change of variables, as it happens to give the correct answer in the first instance.

Comment: Please check the values by those two integrals for the exponential distribution with parameter $1$ i.e. $f(y) = e^{-y}$. The two values are different.

Comment: I was aware that something must be wrong with my reasoning for the second integral, if not the first, and so wanted to understand where I was going wrong. I still believe that T is the correct answer for the first integral, and this is what I obtain using the example that you suggest (splitting the integral into the regions [-T,0) and [0,$\infty$) and summing the results). For the latter region alone, corresponding to the second integral, I get $1-e^{-T}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the method of the other question, but writing the integrals explicitly,
$$ \int_{s=-T}^{\infty} (F(s+T)-F(s)) \, ds = \int_{s=-T}^{\infty} \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \mathbf{1}_{s<t<s+T} \, dt \, ds =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \int_{s=-T}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{s<t<s+T} \, ds \, dt. $$

The characteristic function can be rewritten as $\mathbf{1}_{t-T<s<t}$.

Now we see that the inner integral is more complicated than the other question: if $t>T$, we still get $T$, but otherwise it is different:
$$ \int_{s=-T}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{t-T<s<t} \, ds = \lvert (-T,\infty) \cap (t-T,t) \rvert = 
\begin{cases} 
T & 0<t \\
t+T & -T\leq t \leq 0 \\ 
0 & t<-T \end{cases} $$

Hence the integral is 
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \int_{s=-T}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{t-T<s<t} \, ds \, dt &= \int_{t=0}^{\infty} T f(t) \, dt + \int_{t=-T}^0 (t+T) f(t) \, dt \\
&= T(1-F(0)) + \int_{t=-T}^0 (t+T) f(t) \, dt \\
&= T(1-F(0)) + [(t+T)F(t)]_{-T}^0 - \int_{t=-T}^0 F(t) \, dt \\
&= T-\int_{t=-T}^0 F(t) \, dt.
\end{align}